# java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed on java socket chatting

Tags: java, serversocket

I’m a totally newbie of Java. My homework is Java Socket Chatting.
but there’s an error in Client’s Socket.

Belows are my Server-side codes.

```
public class Server {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int port = 1234;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            HashMap<String, Object> clientMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                ServerProcess sp = new ServerProcess(socket, clientMap);
                sp.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ServerProcess extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private String id;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private Map<String, Object> clientMap;
    public ServerProcess(Socket socket, Map<String, Object> clientMap2) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientMap = clientMap2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and my client codes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        InputStreamReader keyboard = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader input = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost",1234);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            
            ClientServerProcess csp = new ClientServerProcess(socket,br);
            csp.start();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

class ClientServerProcess extends Thread {
    private Socket socket=null;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private BufferedReader br = null;
    public ClientServerProcess(Socket socket,BufferedReader br) {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.br=br;
        isRunning = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //the error is thrown on this line.
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

the error message is

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:943)
    at consoleChat.ClientServerProcess.run(Client.java:75)
```

the connection between Server and Client is successful. but when I execute `socket.getInputStream` the above error message is thrown.
I have no idea why this error is thrown.
Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

Comment: I've run this code and it doesn't give me the same error you get - it 'works' for me.  However, at risk of helping you with your homework ;-), I'll make some observations.  You should not share Socket objects between threads as you can't be sure what the other threads may be doing with it. It kinda works in your case as you only have 2 threads and neither of them do anything with it.  Also, you've created a BufferedReader from the same Socket.getInputStream() in both the main() method and the run() method and one overwrites the other. There are other issues but I've run out of space

Comment: You need to add a condition so the server does not close. A simple way add a while(true) inside the run of the ServerProcess and just print what the  client sends.